# Android device diagnostic application?

Tags: applications, 2.3-gingerbread, bugs, lg-nitro-hd

My Android phone (LG-P930) with Gingerbread is giving "free games" for several weaks now. I recently lost the telephone application and I had to reboot the phone. Few days ago, the phone hang ringing and I could not stop it (grrrr....!)

I'm wondering if there exists an app that could be used to diagnose the device. Something that scan the memory and the different components like some apps we can find on PC.

If you have any other idea about a solution to solve the problem you will be more than welcome!

Dominique

Answer (score 0):

Try wiping data and cache, and if it doesn't help, reflash ROM to your phone via KDZ Updater.

Comment: This option should be the LAST RESORT. He would lose all data.

Comment: Oh, I forgot about saying "Backup your data first".

Comment: Thanks, I'll see how it can help. Of course, I'll try to backup everything.